Is it possible to group sculpting brushes to adjust settings for selected brushes only?
This is my goal:
I want to group certain brushes to share a brush size setting. I imagine it like in Nomad Sculpt, for those who are familiar. Brushes that are used for broad strokes like draw or clay strips share a brush size, while others like smooth and flatten share another, and things like grab and elastic deform another again.
This is super useful as I rarely need the same size for ALL brushes, but I also don't need individual sizes for each brush. Having assignable brush groups that share certain settings would be extremely useful. Ideally you'd have control over which settings are shared and which aren't.
I am sure there must exist an addon that adds this functionality, but I can't seem to find it. Anybody got any pointers for me? Thank you!
